# What is the change in the form of energy that is shown by the change in direction of the compass needle when an electric current is passed beneath it?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity

If the magnetic field generated by the electric current does not move the compass needle, no work is done, thus no energy is exchanged. If the magnetic field generated by the electric current does move the compass needle, the magnetic field generated by the electric current is weakening the magnetic field of the compass needle(a small magnet!) by the magnetic domain theory. Energy lost by the compass's magnetic field is converted to kinetic energy, which allows the needle to change in direction.

Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic needle will rotate to align with the external magnetic field, which in the case you've described is the sum of the Earth's magnetic field at the location of the needle, and the magnetic field generated by the current in the wire, with no significant change in the needle's internal field.

You can think of it as if the needle has a "north" magnetic pole at one end and a "south" magnetic pole at the other end.  One is pulled in the direction of the magnetic field lines, and the other is pulled in the opposite direction, until the needle is aligned with the field lines.

Kinetic energy doesn't really play a role, because the needle can move slowly (e.g., in oil) and it will still align with the external field.  *Potential* energy, though, plays a central role.  The two ends of the needle experience forces that pull them in a direction that will minimize their potential energy in the external field.

Comment: Could you expand on the idea of potential energy here? You usually don't hear about the potential energy associated with the magnetic field.

Comment: Hmm interesting... I guess I had never considered that if $\mathbf J=0$ and $\frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}=0$ that $\nabla\times\mathbf B=0$ and so we could take the field to be conservative and have a potential energy associated with it. Is this correct?

Comment: Wikipedia: "Magnetic energy and electrostatic potential energy are related by Maxwell's equations. The potential energy of a magnet of magnetic moment m
in a magnetic field B is defined as the mechanical work of the magnetic force (actually magnetic torque) on the re-alignment of the vector of the Magnetic dipole moment and is equal to E(p,m)=m⋅B." Change in potential energy can also be calculated as total change of field energy due to change in the configuration (i.e., change in orientation of the dipole).

Comment: Is my comment correct then?

Comment: Yes, the field is conservative.  There might be some debate about exactly what potential energy is, but the math works.

Comment: haha ok fair enough